# Expectation property for Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution

Let X be a random variable having a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Prove that, for n = 1; 2,....E[X$^{n}$] = $\lambda$E[(X + 1)$^{n-1}$].

This is what I tried to do:
[image]

Comment: This proposition is sometimes called the Robbins lemma, after Herbert Robbins, who made use of it in his work as a statistician in the insurance industry in the 1950s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use induction here. For $n=1$ we have
$$
\mathbb E[X^1] = \lambda = \lambda\cdot\mathbb E[(X+1)^0].
$$
Assume now that $\mathbb E[X^n] = \lambda\cdot\mathbb E[(X+1)^{n-1}]$ for some positive integer $n$. Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X^n] &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k^n e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}\\
&= \lambda\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^{n-1}e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\\
&= \lambda\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)^{n-1}e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}\\
&= \lambda\cdot\mathbb E[(X+1)^{n-1}].
\end{align}